# ErrorException Trying to get property 'User' of non-object ( laravel )

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am getting the error:

> ErrorException Trying to get property 'User' of non-object

from the  statements below which don't seem to work:

```
$user = Mobile::find(3)->User;

dd($user);
```

rest of the code is as follows:

**usercontroller.php**

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Models\User;
    use App\Models\Mobile;
    use Hash;
    
    class UserController extends Controller
    {
        public function addUserMobile()
        {
            $user = new User;
            $user->name = "Test Name";
            $user->email = "test@mnp.com";
            $user->password = Hash::make("12345678");
            $user->save();
    
            $mobile = new Mobile;
            $mobile->mobile = '123456789';
            $user->mobile()->save($mobile);
        }
        public function index()
    {
        // get user and mobile data from User model
        $user = User::find(3);
        // var_dump($user->name);
        // var_dump($user->mobile->mobile);
    
        // // get user data from Mobile model
        $user = Mobile::find(3)->User;
        dd($user);
    
        // // get mobile number from User model
        //  $mobile = User::find(3)->mobile;
        // dd($mobile);
    }
    }
```

**mobile.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
    public function mobile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Mobile::class);
        // note: we can also inlcude Mobile model like: 'App\Mobile'
    }
}
```

**mobile table.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateMobilesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('mobiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->string('mobile');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('mobiles');
    }
}
```

**mobile database**

[image: mobile database]

**user database**

[image: user database]

**"3" is user_id btw.**

Comment: Mobile::find(3)->User; in this line you try to get the mobile with id 3, not the mobile with user_id 3... Mobile::where('user_id', 3)->first() wil get the object Mobile with user_id 3. You should also take a look at relationships in the models (hasOne, belongsTo), That would make this a lot easier. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Comment: And one to many in this case (hasMany) https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: Kindly show you Mobile model code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are querying the Mobile with id 3 (which does not exist) and then calling the `user` relation.

```php
$user = Mobile::find(3)->user;
```

Since `Mobile::find` with an id that doesn't exist returns null, you are calling `->user` on `null`, and you will get the error you mentioned.

Also, you should add a `belongsTo` relation in your Mobile model:

```php
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Now, after fixing your query to use `user_id`, you can do:

```php
$user = Mobile::where('user_id', 3)->first()->user;
```